# Translate objective-c into ruby

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am developing a Rubymotion app. I am using the pod KNSemiModalViewController.
How can I "translate" this Objective-C code into ruby?

```
[self presentSemiViewController:semiVC withOptions:@{
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack    : @(YES),
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration : @(0.3),
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity     : @(0.8),
     }];
```

Comment: If your going to be successful with the Cocoa/OS X APIs, you'll need to know Objective-C well enough to write an app in it in the first place (as all the APIs and most examples are written in ObjC).....

Comment: Yes, I am almost finished with the app. I just need to know how to write the above code in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.presentSemiViewController(semiVC, withOptions:{
  KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack => true,
  KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration => 0.3,
  KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity => 0.8
})
```

Comment: Well this does not seem to work unfortunately. I get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'TypeError', reason: 'unrecognized runtime type `' (TypeError)

Comment: I see this answer has been accepted, although @Jonathan Clark reports it does not seem to work. Perhaps this would work: `self.presentSemiViewController(semiVC, withOptions:-> { KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack = true, KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration = 0.3, KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity = 0.8 })`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to work out the Ruby side of things yourself, but this line of code:

```
[self presentSemiViewController:semiVC withOptions:@{
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack    : @(YES),
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration : @(0.3),
     KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity     : @(0.8),
     }];
```

Is the same as this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary, dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES], KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack,
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3], KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration,
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:08], KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity];

[self presentSemiViewController:semiVC withOptions:dict];
```

Assuming that `KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack` is using dot notation to execute a method, each of those could be rewritten as `[KNSemiModalOptionKeys pushParentBack]`.

Hopefully, that gives you enough info on the ObjC side to translate to Ruby (which is quite adept at forming dictionaries, IIRC).

Answer (score -2):

I've seen a Sublime plugin objc2rubymotion, never tried.

There is a web page based on it http://objc2rubymotion.herokuapp.com

Never tried as well but it might help rubyists falling down in iOS environment like me :)